# Função javascript dentro de innerHTML não funciona

Tags: javascript

Bom dia.

Minha função Ajax devolve uma string e imprime-a via innerHTML dentro de uma div. Essa string é esta:

```
<div>
    <p>Login bem sucedido.</p>
    <p>Redirecionamento em ação.</p>
</div>
<script> location.reload(); </script>
```

Já fiz isso em outros projetos, mas a função não realiza reload da página. Tentei também um um alert, mas não funcionou de jeito nenhum.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Segue função success do ajax:

```
function success(value) {
    if (value.length > 0) {
        // msg = elmento div#msg
        msg.innerHTML = value;
    } else {
        msg.innerHTML = ('<div id="error"><div class="inform"><p>Nenhum valor retornado.</p></div></div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, se tu fizer um reload o usuário nem vai ver a mensagem direito (ou nem vai ver, já que a página seria recarregada imediatamente). É isso mesmo que vc quer?

Comment: Já tentou o clássico `setTimeout(function() {
    document.location.reload(true);
}, 5000);`

Comment: Boa tarde, @Sam. O intuito é colocar um setTimeout, mas nenhuma função funciona: seja o reload sozinho, o setTimeout, ou o alert.

Comment: Boa tarde, @FabianoMonteiro. Tentei de tudo. Nenhuma função funciona.

Comment: ja tentou fazer o load para dentro da div? ou chama html(str) do jquery

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @E.Coelho Você só quer um reload? E qual o objetivo do reload? O seu código com o `setTimeout`, aqui no meu PC funciona. Fica dando reload. Acho melhor explicar qual seu objetivo com isso, e o que há no seu sistema atualmente.
Você tem que chamar `appendChild` para anexar o elemento DOM a um elemento existente.

Comment: Acho que o mais importante é checar se tem alguma mensagem de erro no console do navegador. A partir disso fica mais fácil descobrir o problema, pois com as informações atuais qualquer ajuda é chute.

Comment: Boa tarde, @JasarOrion. Não estou utilizando bibliotecas neste projeto. Sobre o uso da função .load(), nunca a utilizei em meus projetos. Sempre usei o .html() em jQuery.

Comment: Boa tarde, @FabianoMonteiro. Eu quero que as funções funcionem. Estou usando javascript puro neste projeto. Vou tentar o appendChild e já dou um feedback.

Comment: Boa tarde, @fernandosavio. Não há mensagem de erro no console. Vou tentar o appendChild, como Fabiano falou e já dou um feedback.

Comment: Com jQuery o código funciona, mas com JS puro não porque o retorno vem como string. Agora, porquê no jQuery funciona é que não sei.

Comment: Coloca o código do Ajax também, o problema pode ser ali.

Comment: @E.Coelho Vou passar um código, até onde entendi o que você quer: `<div id="meuidentificador"></div><script>document.getElementById("meuidentificador").innerHTML += "<p>Login bem sucedido.</p><p>Redirecionamento em ação.</p>" + setTimeout(function() { document.location.reload(true); }, 5000);</script>` Só não entendi o seguinte é reload ou redirecionamento?

Comment: @fernandosavio, eu editei a pergunta, colocando a função success(). Tentei o appendChild, mas não deu certo: ele trata o código HTML como texto e printa <div>Mensagem... (etc).

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro, a página é dinâmica na base: se a sessão estiver iniciada, ele incluirá outra página, caso contrário, continuará no form de login. Há "impressão" de redirecionamento para o usuário. Ao realizar o reload(), o PHP verifica que a sessão foi iniciada em inclui o painel de opções para o usuário.

Comment: Ainda tá difícil saber de onde vem o erro com pouca informação. Fiz [esse snippet](https://codepen.io/fernandosavio/pen/axEGWP) que faz uma requisição ajax e usa `innerHTML` e tudo funciona muito bem.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta encontrada: developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Trecho do artigo:

```
name = "<script>alert('I am John in an annoying alert!')</script>"; 
el.innerHTML = name; // inofensivo, nesse caso
```

*Embora isso talvez se pareça como um ataque cross-site scripting, o resultado é inofensivo. O HTML5 especifica que uma tag , inserida via innerHTML, não deve ser executada.*

Não sei o que fazer... (risos)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Encontrei!

Encontrei uma forma fácil de lidar com o problema. A função success() ficou assim:

```
function success(value) {
    if (value.length > 0) {
        // msg = elmento div#msg
        msg.innerHTML = value;
        var scripts = msg.getElementsByTagName("script");
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            eval(scripts[i].innerText);
        }
    } else {
        msg.innerHTML = ('<div id="error"><div class="inform"><p>Nenhum valor retornado.</p></div></div>');
    }
}
```

Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Espero que ajude alguém.

Grande abraço e obrigado a todos!